# How to make image change on a hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to think of ways to do this but I haven't figured one out yet, so I thought I'd ask here!
So for example I have this:

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="arrow.png"/>Index</a>
```

I want that on hovering Index, the image should change to arrow_hover.png, using CSS.

Comment: that's not possible with css.

Comment: I think you can make arrow.png a background image

Comment: Might this help? http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/show-image-on-hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pseudo class `:hover`

First, give the image a class so that it doesn't target every img. Say, `hover-image`

Then...

```
.hover-image:hover {
    background: url('arrow_hover.png');
}
```

HOWEVER! THIS WILL NOT WORK! Using only CSS, you cannot change an images attribute `src`. You will need to use javascript.

You can change this to a `div` instead of an `img` tag, and this code will work. But not with your current markup.

To do this in javascript, give the element an id to make things easier. In this case.. `derp`.

You would do:

```
var x = document.getElementById("derp");
x.mouseenter = function() {
    this.src = "arrow_hover.png";
}
x.mouseout = function() {
    this.src = "arrow.png";
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you for your replies. How would I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Updated my answer for you

Comment: Would the a or image have the element?

Comment: I mean, which one would have the id?

Comment: the img would have the id since it has the src attribute

Comment: how would the image change on hovering the link text?

Comment: According to your HTML, the image IS the link. But if you want to include both, just change the id to the anchor tag. The rest is up to you, google helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with CSS only. Try this CSS:

```
#theImage {
height:250px; //Or whatever size it needs to be
width:320px; //Or, again, whatever it needs to be
background-image:url(stuff.jpg);
}
#theImage:hover {
background-image:url(otherstuff.jpg);
}
```

`#theImage` would be a div.